# Why does XhtmlTextWriter ignore custom attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmltextwriter

I've found some weird behaviour and I was wondering if anyone can help out here.

I'm creating a form using the XhtmlTextWriter class that inherits the addAttribute methods. I'm creating an `input` tag that needs a nice (HTML5) placeholder attribute. The `addAttribute` method has two parameters: the attribute name and the value. The attribute name can either be picked from the `HtmlTextWriteAttribute` enum or inputted manually as a string. Since 'placeholder' is not available in the enum, I used the following code:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XhtmlTextWriter html = new XhtmlTextWriter(sw);
html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text");
html.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "firstname");
html.AddAttribute("placeholder", "First Name");
html.AddAttribute("maxlength", "25");
html.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
html.RenderEndTag();//input
return sw.ToString();
```

This nicely creates the element & attributes specified... EXCEPT for placeholder:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="25"></input>
```

Does anyone know where my placeholder is? (As you can see with `maxlength`, using a string for attribute name works...)

Note: This does work, but it's not so pretty:

```
html.WriteBeginTag("input"); 
html.WriteAttribute("type", "text");
html.WriteAttribute("placeholder", "First Name");
html.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd);
```

// Update: Same problem with the `required` attribute... Could it be something HTML5 specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using `XhtmlTextWriter`, which is strict with its attributes and won't write out unrecognised ones (due to the need to produce valid XHTML). You have two options.

**One:** Use `HtmlTextWriter` instead:

```
HtmlTextWriter html = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
```

**Two:** If you need to use `XhtmlTextWriter` for some reason, you can add `placeholder` as a recognised attribute for `input` elements before you add the attribute to the element:

```
html.AddRecognizedAttribute("input", "placeholder");
```

Comment: Aha, that sounds reasonable. I'd like to conform myself to HTML5. MSDN says on the XhtmlTextWriter page that "The HtmlTextWriter outputs XHTML unless you configure ASP.NET specifically to not render XHTML markup", so I'm leaning towards your first solution. 
What would you recommend? 
(I'll check my code tomorrow, you'll get your checkmark then)